# How can I repeat a public class in Java?

Tags: java, class, loops, repeat, public

I looked for a long time for a possibility to repeat a public class in Java, I found a solution with continue and repeating an additional while loop. But I am really not happy with it, is there a simpler method do to this? 
Thanks for the help guys.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Zufallszahl {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (1 == 1) { 
            Random rn = new Random();
            Scanner numberScan = new Scanner(System.in);
            Scanner restartScan = new Scanner(System.in);
            int zahl = rn.nextInt(100 - 1) + 1;
            int number = 0;
            String restart = "";
            int a = 0;

            while (number != zahl) {
                a++;
                System.out.print("Rate eine Zahl zwischen 0 und 100: ");
                number = numberScan.nextInt();
                if (number == zahl) {
                    System.out.println("richtig");
                    System.out.println("Du hast " + a + " Versuche gebraucht!");
                    System.out.print("Nochmal? j/n: ");
                    restart = restartScan.nextLine();

                }
                if (number < zahl) {
                    System.out.println("zu klein");
                }
                if (number > zahl) {
                    System.out.println("zu gross");
                }

            }
            if (restart.equalsIgnoreCase("j")) {
                continue;
            } else if (restart.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
                System.out.println("Tschüss!");
                return;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You want to **repeat** a class? What do you want to do? Info: with **break** you can leave/exit the **current loop**, **return** will leave/exit the **whole method**. Maybe you can just try to replace **return** with **break**

Comment: Yes, I want to "restart" the complete code
 if (restart.equalsIgnoreCase("j")) {
                continue;
with thist It starts again but I had to do an additional loop in the class wrapping everithing. I dont think it s a good way to do.

Comment: You can just re-call `main(new String[0])` at the end of your method (instead of **return** and/or **continue**)

Comment: but ist thist while loop necessary? Or is there an other possibility to restart a class?

Comment: Hey thanks Ben It worked like a charm!

Comment: you can get rid of the first while by adding your restricting to the second one:  while (number != zahl || restart.equalsIgnoreCase("j")). You will need to change some logic though to assign a new value to your random number

Comment: @Ben wouldn't that add to the stack on each restart? If i play long enough, i'll get a StackOverflow

Comment: Yes it would! But I don't think that you'll get a stackoverflow when playing this game. It's not very exciting.... ;)

Comment: Even if nobody will ever play this game until a stackoverflow happens this solution is very bad practise. I recommend the solution of @pandaadb

Comment: @ArcticLord: That is why I didn't create an answer. I didn't test it, but the original solution (with **while (1==1)** && **continue**) should have worked as far as i can see.

Comment: So is the solution of @pandaadb the right way to go? 
I know it's a borring game ;) but it's about restarting a class :D I found no solutions somwehere else. So I asume it's not very common to restart a class?

Comment: @Ben yes it worked. But it s a lot of unessesary additonal code init?

Comment: You don't **restart** a class. It's a simple method which contains a loop.

Comment: I am going to create an answer...

Comment: After testing your code, it is not clear to me what your problem is. Your code works great (as far as I can see). Further: The 2 loops are needed. Outer loop for restart the whole game (generate new number). Inner loop for the game itself (guess the number)...

Comment: @thefox: The other answers are not really better than yours. I don't see much benefit by creating an own class with just one single method, which is doing the same as yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About restarting - that seems odd unless you are extracting it in an object. So solution 1 may be to just run in a loop and get rid of the first one, by checking the restart in the second:

```
while (number != zahl || restart.equalsIgnoreCase("j")) { ... }
```

Note that you will need to change your logic to reassing a new random number. Alternatively, restarting could be done by creating a game class that allows you to execute it. For example smth like this:

```
public class Zufallszahl {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        Game g = new Game();
        Random rn = new Random();
        while(true) {
            g.start(rn.nextInt(100 -1) + 1, s);
            System.out.println("Noch ne Runde? Y/N");
            String response = s.next();
            if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) return;
        }
    }

    public static class Game { 

        public void start(final int numberToGuess, final Scanner s) {
            int number = 0;
            int a = 0;
            while (number != numberToGuess ) {
                a++;
                System.out.print("Rate eine Zahl zwischen 0 und 100: ");
                number = s.nextInt();
                if (number == numberToGuess) {
                    System.out.println("richtig");
                    System.out.println("Du hast " + a + " Versuche gebraucht!");
                    return;
                }
                if (number < numberToGuess) {
                    System.out.println("zu klein");
                }
                if (number > numberToGuess) {
                    System.out.println("zu gross");
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Hey you code works but you should consider to start codinge more object orientated like this:

```
public class Filesplitter {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */

public static int eingabe;
public static int rnd;
public static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
public static Random rn = new Random();
public static int counter = 0;
public static boolean a = true;
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
   while (a = true){
       eingabe = 0;
       rnd = rn.nextInt(100 - 1)+1;
       while (!zahlCheck()){

           eingabezahl();
       }
       System.out.print("möchten sie noch mal spielen ? j/n: ");
       if(sc.next().equals("j")){
       a = true;
        }
       else {
       a = false;
       }
   }
}
public static boolean zahlCheck(){
    if(eingabe == 0){

    }
    else if(eingabe != rnd){
        if(eingabe < rnd)
            System.out.println("Die zahl ist zu klein");
        else
            System.out.println("Die zahl ist zu groß");
        return false;
    }else {
        System.out.println("Richtig !\n Du hast "+counter+" Versuche gebraucht.");
    return true;
    }
    return false;
}
public static int eingabezahl(){
    System.out.println("Bitte geben sie eine Zahl ein:");
    eingabe = sc.nextInt();
    counter +=1;
    return 1;
}
```

}

this will make things way easier since you can just call your methode in side your loop ;)

Comment: OK, so where is the special OO-Part then?